# CDK Deploy-Step Fails "Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy some code using codepipline and I get the error below. My CDK code is very simple and not using lambda function. However, this may be the result of some default settings.

```bash
Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred while GetObject. 
S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey. S3 Error Message: The specified key does not exist. 
(Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 3160ff16-1e4a-4a38-b609-34820a1d9a8f)"
(RequestToken: a8b5eecf-8c1d-d90f-e18f-390a05734944, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

The error is also reported in the aws-cdk Github page but the issue was closed without a comprehensive conclusion: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/22198

Additional information: I've also tried to deploy via 'cdk deploy' which copies the asset(s) to the S3 bucket but it does not resolve this issue.

Can anyone share any hints to resolve this issue?

My `aws-cdk-lib` version is `2.40.0`.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here: have you bootstrapped your AWS account for AWS CDK? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html

Comment: If you are using CDK Pipelines, disabling self-mutation can cause this.